# What does it mean when we say cassandra is scalable?

Tags: cassandra

I have created two node Cassandra cluster and try  to perform load test. I  find that one node or two node not making much difference in the through put I have supposed if 1 node can provide me 2000 tps  for insert the two node should double the amount. Is it work like that? 
if it is not then what actually Scaling means and how can I relate with it latency or throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is scalable. Just your case is a bit simplified since two nodes is not really the case of high scalability. You should be aware or the token partitioning algorithm used by Cassandra. As soon as you understand it, there should not be any quesitons. There is plenty of presentations about that. E.g. this one: http://www.datastax.com/resources/tutorials/partitioning-and-replication

In case of replication factor 1 everything is simple:
Each key-value pair you save/read from/to Cassandra is a query to one of Cassandra nodes in the cluster. Data is evenly distributed among nodes (see details of partitioning algorithm). So you always have total load evenly distributed among all nodes -> more nodes you have more load they can carry (and it is linear). In this case the system should of course be configured in a right way to avoid different kinds of network bottlenecks.

In case of replication factor more than 1 the situation is a bit more complicated, however the principle is the same.

Comment: You mean to Say that scaling is all about Sharing load and Not about increasing Throughput.?

Comment: +1 "two nodes is not really the case of high scalability."  That is precisely what I was trying to explain at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of factors that contribute to this result.

A) check your replication factor. Although not desirable, in your case you can set it to 1

B) look into the shard in your primary key. If in your tests you are not changing it, then you are loading the data skewed and that the table is not scaling out to 2 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> What does it mean when we say Casssandra is scalable?

There are basically two ways to scale a database.

- **Vertical scaling**: Increasing the resources of the existing nodes in your cluster (more RAM, faster HDDs, more cores).
- **Horizontal scaling**: Adding additional nodes to your cluster.

Vertical scaling tends to be more of a "band-aid" or temporary solution, because it has very finite limits.  Your machines will only support so much RAM or so many cores, and once you max that out you really don't have anywhere to go.

Cassandra is "scalable" because it simplifies *horizontal* scaling.  If you find that your existing nodes are maxing-out their available resources, you can simply add another node(s), adjust your replication factor, and run a `nodetool repair`.  If you have had to do this with other database products, you will appreciate how (relatively) easy Cassandra makes it.

In your case, it's hard to know what exactly is going on without (a lot) more detail.  But if your load tests are being adequately handled by your first node, then I can see why you wouldn't notice much of a difference by adding another.

If you haven't already, check out the [Cassandra Stress Tool](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsCStress_t.html).

Additionally, be sure to check your current methods against this article, which is appropriately titled: [How not to benchmark Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-not-to-benchmark-cassandra)